# Run apps from xcode to a device wireless?

Tags: xcode, ios

Is there a way to run apps over air from xcode?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know: no.

It is possible to distribute your [ad-hoc] apps over the air though.
http://nachbaur.com/blog/building-ios-apps-for-over-the-air-adhoc-distribution

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@mustafasait1461/practicing-wireless-development-in-xcode-9-beta-58d5f028f487 ## Here is a tutorial how to do this. ##

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please try to contain most relevant information from the link in your post. Read more about it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251609/should-old-high-rep-link-only-accepted-answers-be-deleted).